# Instagram v VSCO v 'website or forum'

Tags: discussion

[How can I simultaneously download original pictures from someone else's public VSCO?](https://superuser.com/q/1487382/269574)

[How can I download some original-sized bigger pictures from Instagram simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/q/1482166/269574)

https://superuser.com/q/1487356/269574 (Now deleted)

How are these duplicates?

I don't know computer science, and to me, Instagram ostensibly differs from VSCO, and they both aren't regular websites or forums.

Answer (score 9):

Your lack of research and any indication of what you have tried so far, combined with the fact that websites are off topic here, make them duplicates.

Per the help centre:

> not about … websites or web services

We shouldn't really have to care about what website you are having trouble with. To us they are all just something you should use a browser or downloader tool to deal with. That a tool might work with one site and not another might be important but it shouldn't be up to people to find The One Tool To Rule Them All.

Ignoring the different websites your questions are effectively identical and simply ask "How do I download images from a website?"

Okay, so you mention using Instagram Downloader. Fine, a program in your web browser. Is there anything about it that suggests it can do what you want? What makes you think we can change that? How do you expect us to help you change the behaviour?

We already have a [good number of more generic questions and answers](https://superuser.com/search?q=download%20pictures%20from%20website) which suggest wget or other tools. There may well be better tools, but going shopping for them is off topic here and you have already [asked on Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69348/browser-addon-to-simultaneously-download-original-pictures-from-someone-elses-p) (which makes your questions cross-site duplicates) so you need to tell us how you expect us to be able to help you fix your specific problem.

There is a hierarchy to your problem.

1. Downloading everything is easy
2. Downloading specific things needs specific tools

   - those tools need to understand what they are downloading, at least enough that they can let you choose things
3. Knowing what *exactly* you want to download, which version of it, where to, and with what name requires meatware. Either you need to do it manually or you need to write a tool. Lacking the ability to do one, you should do the other.

We are site about problem solving on a computer, but you have to come to us with some indication that you know the intricacies of the problem to begin with.

1. Know that this is a problem that *could* be solved in the first place
2. Be *actively* working towards the solving the problem yourself as well.

A lot of your questions read like you tried one vaguely related thing and then gave up and came here to "get the nerds to fix it". You are rarely actively involved in solving your problem and that is a problem for us. It might be a language barrier thing, but all of your recent (and many of your old) questions have just been (in almost as many words) "I can't do x, how do I do x?" With no context.

Case in point: [In Adobe Acrobat, how can I pick my Custom Color with merely 1 click?](https://superuser.com/questions/1487391/in-adobe-acrobat-how-can-i-pick-my-custom-color-with-merely-1-click)

This is nothing more than a gif and a question of how to not click as much even though it is obvious that that is the number of clicks needed. What makes you believe that it can be reduced? Did you accidentally do it quicker once? Is there a keyboard shortcut? Have you tried tools like AutoIt or AutoHotkey? (I'm certain I've suggested those to you in the past)

So what *exactly* do you expect us to help with? Assume that some of these features are written by the programmers of the software and that they are hard-coded to work that way. How exactly do you intend for us to be helpful to you? How do you expect us to be able to solve it?

We are also not a script writing service. If you are expecting someone to write a script or tool to do the work for you then you are in the wrong place. Many people, myself included, may drop what we were doing to bash out a few lines of script if someone is obviously struggling and in need of help, but you come across as having already decided to offload the problem to someone else and avoiding the struggle.

These are your problems. **Own them**.

Helping us to help you is key.